# Filter text read from a file in Windows DOS batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to read in the contents of multiple .txt files and output the contents of each to a single file. The hitch is that the .txt files I'm reading are the email address I want, and then a tab. The single output file I'd like a just have the email address enclosed in quotes.

So the input file will be

```
email1@test.com{tab}  
email2@test.com{tab}
```

and the output should be

```
'email1@test.com',  
'email2@test.com',  
'email3@test.com',  
'email4@test.com',
```

Note that the output file will be a concatenation of all input files read.

Here is what I have so far to read all the input files. How do I craft the DO so that at the very least it will remove the tab, and for bonus points add in the quotes and commas.

```
FOR %%f IN (Names\CaseName_*.txt) DO TYPE %%f >> List_of_Accounts.txt
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

As the default token separator is whitespace the following works ok given your sample input:

```
for /f "tokens=1" %i in (em1.txt em2.txt) do echo '%i', >> output.txt
```

or to get a wildcard in there:

```
for %f in (em*.txt) do for /f "tokens=1" %i in (%f) do echo '%i', >> output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Since tab is part of the default, the "token" bit isn't required. Here's the final code.    FOR %%f IN (CaseName_*.txt)  DO (FOR /F %%l IN ( %%f ) DO ECHO \'%%l\',) >> List_of_Accounts.txt